# how to display reply from dm discord.py

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

this is my dm code

```py
@client.command()
async def dm(ctx, user_id=None, *, args= None):
    if user_id != None and args != None:
        try:
            target=await client.fetch_user(user_id)
            await target.send(args)
            await ctx.channel.send("'"+args+"'ได้ถูกส่งไปที่ : " + target.name)
        except:
            await ctx.channel.send("ไม่สารมารถ dm ได้")
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send("A user_id / or arguments were not included.")
```

i wanted to take the response or just like anything that random person dm the bot and display by print('') or ctx.channel.send how do i do that ? please help

I have solve my problem by doing

````
async def on_message(message):
if message.guild is None and not message.author.bot:
        print(f'{message.author } :' + f'ID :{message.author.id} :' + message.content)
    await client.process_commands(message)```
````

Answer (score -1):

Your question is neither well researched, nor explainative to people trying to help you. And unfortunately its unreadable too. You shouldn't expect your question to be answered as noone wants to solve your problem when they have to decode the question by themselves. For future questions, please read [`How do I ask a good question`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Still, heres your answer:

```
# Events are not costum commands but specific actions, like on_message
# The on_message event doesnt pass a Context, but only a message object
# For the context, run client.get_context(message)
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Message is, like context, a class. This means you can get a variety of information from message,
    # like the author name or id

    # check that the bot ignores its own messages
    if message.author.id != client.user.id:
        # Check if the channel is a DM channel
        if isinstance(message.channel, discord.channel.DMChannel):
            answer = f"{message.author.name}: {message.content}"
            # Provide the channelid of the channel you want the message to be sent to.
            # You can do that by enabling Developer Mode in Settings -> Appearance
            # Then you can right click on any channel or member to copy their id
            channelid = 1111 # 18-digit-integer
            channel = client.get_channel(channelid)

            await channel.send(answer)
```

Comment: Sorry. I posted my mistake and i have solved it long ago thank you so much